Flutter sliver How to achieve this nested scrolling layout?
I want to achieve a complex scrolling behavior in flutter. I assume sliver is the way to go but I could not find a way to solve my problem.
Here is a screen of the content I want to scroll:

The behavior I want is the following:

First the green and red panel needs to scroll with the title keep centered position
Second when not more space is available the title goes out of the viewport
Third the red and green panel say pinned at the top of the viewport and the text only scroll under the "Content" and "Quiz" bar

I should be able to do the sticky green and red panel with SliverPinnedHeader from the sliver_tools the title container scale down as well maybe with SliverAppBar or something.
I struggle to find how to start the scrolling of the text in the green panel only because the text is inside Row and Column widgets that are not SliverWidget (inside a SliverToBoxAdapter widget). I need a nested scroll view that is "linked" to the root widget to make is scroll when needed somehow.
Widget build(context) {
Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: FPColors.primaryDarker,
                  height: 400,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/background/svg/pattern.svg',
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                ),
                CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: [
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 370,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Title",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ),
                    SliverPadding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 0,
                        left: 16,
                        right: 16,
                      ),
                      sliver: SliverCrossAxisGroup(
                        slivers: [
                          SliverCrossAxisExpanded(
                            flex: 3,
                            sliver: EbpModuleContent(ebpModule),
                          ),
                          const SliverConstrainedCrossAxis(
                            maxExtent: 16,
                            sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox.shrink()),
                          ),
                          SliverCrossAxisExpanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            sliver: SliverSticky(
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                                height: 400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
}


class Content extends StatelessWidget {
  const Content({super.key});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      const Text('Sommaire'),
                      const Spacer(),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Gap(8),
                  const Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text('Introduction'),
                      Gap(8),
                      Text('Chapter 1'),
                      Gap(8),
                      Text('Chapter 2'),
                      Gap(8),
                      Text('Chapter 3'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const Gap(8),
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const TabBar([
                    TabBarItem('Content', Icons.article),
                    TabBarItem('Quiz', Icons.quiz),
                    TabBarItem('Commentaire', Icons.comment),
                  ]),
                  const Gap(8),
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Text(
                      List.generate(10, (index) => '''
                      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                      ''').join(' '),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Thanks

I was able to achieve this behavior with this example using NestedScrollView:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyHomePage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 400,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                NestedScrollView(
                  headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 370,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Title",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  body: const Content(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Content extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Content({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            const Text('Sommaire'),
                            const Spacer(),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const Gap(8),
                        const Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Text('Introduction'),
                            Gap(8),
                            Text('Chapter 1'),
                            Gap(8),
                            Text('Chapter 2'),
                            Gap(8),
                            Text('Chapter 3'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Gap(8),
                  const Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: DefaultTabController(
                      length: 3,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TabBar(
                            tabs: [
                              Tab(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [Icon(Icons.article), Gap(4), Text('Content')],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Tab(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [Icon(Icons.quiz), Gap(4), Text('Quiz')],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Tab(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [Icon(Icons.comment), Gap(4), Text('Com')],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                            dividerHeight: 1,
                            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: CustomScrollView(
                              slivers: [
                                SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Text("$lipsum\n$lipsum\n$lipsum")),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Gap(16),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Related content',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                  ),
                  const Gap(8),
                  const Text('Related content 1'),
                  const Gap(8),
                  const Text('Related content 2'),
                  const Gap(8),
                  const Text('Related content 3'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

const lipsum = '''
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut quam sapien, feugiat eu velit in, ullamcorper fermentum orci. Fusce efficitur luctus justo et fermentum. Quisque iaculis, quam quis vehicula congue, massa diam lobortis quam, ac suscipit augue orci quis dolor. Nunc tempor consequat odio a consequat. Vivamus molestie, magna et mattis finibus, ligula sapien iaculis diam, eget volutpat erat nisi a magna. Fusce quis placerat odio. Quisque gravida aliquet arcu, vel cursus erat venenatis quis. Praesent mattis imperdiet justo, imperdiet lobortis orci varius at. Nam commodo non erat non sagittis. Nam tincidunt tristique laoreet. Mauris efficitur, mi id dignissim blandit, quam leo congue nunc, in aliquam tortor ex sit amet nisl. Morbi placerat, nisi in ornare molestie, quam augue consectetur magna, quis ornare enim est quis ex. Sed ac libero vel velit auctor rutrum. Vestibulum dapibus volutpat sem id semper. Pellentesque in lectus nec lectus porttitor gravida sodales eget enim.

Proin tempus tempor lectus in auctor. Praesent et mauris viverra, feugiat sem in, vulputate lacus. Pellentesque sem mauris, ultrices ut vestibulum eget, sodales at turpis. Nulla lorem metus, mattis nec tristique quis, ultrices nec libero. Etiam et aliquam quam. Aenean ut aliquet orci. Etiam rhoncus lorem eu tempus lobortis. Nullam consectetur elit et pulvinar dignissim. Aenean eu varius dui. Quisque gravida, magna quis euismod ullamcorper, dui leo ultricies tellus, ac semper nulla arcu ac libero. Fusce hendrerit nisl non lacus sodales, ac maximus felis varius. Sed accumsan sollicitudin orci a laoreet. Nam ut eleifend ipsum. Duis est eros, euismod ac risus ut, dictum laoreet felis. Ut maximus, quam sit amet pellentesque cursus, leo mi imperdiet dui, in eleifend nibh orci a sapien. Cras rutrum mi in nulla imperdiet convallis.

Sed pretium lectus eu felis dictum pulvinar sit amet sit amet orci. Donec tincidunt, felis sit amet egestas pretium, magna erat efficitur odio, ac molestie nisl ipsum eu elit. Suspendisse varius elementum massa sed tristique. Morbi ultricies magna metus, a tempor eros laoreet in. Nulla vehicula, purus ut elementum venenatis, lacus ex pharetra magna, et posuere leo elit id enim. Maecenas fringilla maximus ultrices. Fusce mattis orci semper efficitur lacinia. Vivamus turpis eros, facilisis non tellus sit amet, accumsan rutrum arcu. Donec hendrerit eros tellus, eu commodo libero molestie quis. Maecenas ultricies aliquet massa, eget gravida leo.

Pellentesque fermentum consectetur odio, a vestibulum sem dictum cursus. Nulla euismod massa ex, ac porttitor sem tristique eu. Integer id luctus eros. Sed non augue urna. Curabitur sapien sem, mattis volutpat massa et, pharetra vehicula odio. Aenean eget ullamcorper erat, eu faucibus odio. Vestibulum quis sapien pellentesque nibh posuere efficitur eu tempor nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus leo nulla, accumsan quis vehicula in, venenatis lobortis arcu. Vivamus volutpat nulla diam, eu condimentum ligula cursus sit amet. Sed viverra tempus dapibus. Sed pharetra tortor eu aliquet auctor. Nulla elementum, ipsum in auctor sagittis, est risus cursus neque, at mattis justo lorem nec diam. Vestibulum tristique aliquam eros, vitae fermentum odio varius nec. Duis urna dolor, vehicula vel eros a, aliquam efficitur ante.

Donec justo tellus, ullamcorper vitae mauris non, tempus molestie tellus. Cras sed orci lorem. Integer tincidunt elit eget metus elementum tristique quis vel massa. Duis et quam sit amet mi lacinia semper quis vel ex. Phasellus ullamcorper eleifend justo, eget placerat quam elementum at. Fusce tempor pellentesque nibh, et ornare felis malesuada ut. Nulla fringilla pharetra sapien non tempus. Nam elementum risus a eros aliquet luctus.

Maecenas at porta augue. Nam nec tempus dui, in dictum arcu. Nam nec libero egestas, vehicula dolor ac, pellentesque ex. Duis mollis turpis ut arcu lacinia, id varius ante fermentum. Nullam et nisl et turpis placerat fermentum. Integer aliquet mattis scelerisque. Quisque sed pellentesque diam. Phasellus a iaculis est.

Maecenas eget blandit sem. Phasellus faucibus dapibus mollis. Sed malesuada est et pellentesque mollis. Ut sed diam tincidunt, viverra mauris sit amet, porta sapien. Mauris ultrices diam id est cursus, ut pulvinar arcu dignissim. Aliquam semper elit quis felis porta, interdum malesuada metus finibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas a consequat lorem. Praesent placerat sem laoreet quam venenatis luctus. Morbi suscipit ullamcorper augue, eu maximus justo tincidunt et. Nullam vel tortor turpis. Fusce ornare augue ut euismod aliquet. Aenean pharetra urna vitae interdum tincidunt.

Quisque tincidunt velit sed ligula commodo sodales. Donec maximus cursus arcu non pretium. Phasellus pellentesque malesuada pellentesque. Suspendisse vitae arcu eu velit tempus condimentum. Sed dapibus porttitor dui vel convallis. Suspendisse eu congue nunc, non convallis quam. Aliquam dignissim id odio a porttitor. Nulla dapibus sem quis ipsum sagittis pretium. Ut tincidunt quis est ut scelerisque.
''';

This still suffer from a bug I reported here
